# Determining a supertype path

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, gnu-common-lisp

Given a variable with content 1, I know that it's a member of at least five types:

```
 1 (let* ((fred 1))
 2   (princ (typep fred 'bit)) (terpri)
 3   (princ (typep fred 'integer)) (terpri)
 4   (princ (typep fred 'fixnum)) (terpri)
 5   (princ (typep fred 'rational)) (terpri)
 6   (princ (typep fred t)) (terpri))
T
T
T
T
T
```

Two questions here.

1. Given a variable with arbitrary content, how do I determine its supertype path?
2. Where could I have found the answer for this in documentation?

Comment: What you are trying to do is also known as [linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). However, CLOS preceded this invention. It was probably first planned for Dylan, but it really only exists in Python or (maybe Perl?). AFAIK, CLOS never enforced any particular linearization rule, so you probably won't be able to find a path, rather a set of all superclasses (i.e. it won't be ordered).

Comment: @wvxvw: yes it does! otherwise the applicable methods would be called in an arbitrary order. See my answer for references.

Comment: @sds I feel uncomfortable reading this: "All methods on this generic function must compute the class precedence list as a function of the ordered direct superclasses of the superclasses of class. The results are undefined if the rules used to compute the class precedence list depend on any other factors." What is "ordered direct superclasses"? How are they supposed to be ordered? I'm more afraid that it might be implementation-defined, and not defined in MOP.

Comment: @wvxvw: The order _is_ well defined in the [ANSI CL standard](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_ce.htm)

Comment: @sds sorry to be a bore, but I can't find where it says how to resolve conflicts (and it uses a lot of ASCII art instead of words). Conflicts as in, for example, how to treat common superclasses inherited through different branches. It mentions that "R" (which is probably a relation over superclasses with inherit-from being this relation's operation, but maybe it's something else - the doc. doesn't say it) can be "it is assumed that they are consistent and that R generates a partial ordering". At the same time it says nothing about what happens when they are inconsistent.

Comment: @wvxvw: I agree that the standard can be opaque at times, but the bottom line is that it _does_ specify the behavior uniquely. If you would like it to be clarified, these comments are not the proper forum - please ask a separate question.

Comment: @sds I think there are two things at once: 1. It, like, for example, C++ does not exhaustively specify how inheritance must be resolved (i.e. when it is inconsistent, the implementation may treat it whichever way it likes). Linearisation is the mechanism to address this issue (why else would it be invented?). 2. is the unintelligible language of the CLHS, which makes the first issue difficult to discover.

Comment: @sds Ah, sorry, nevermind, it does say it is an error, here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_ceb.htm when it discusses the case when classes cannot be ordered. But this would really take awhile to find...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Types

You are asking about **types**, not **classes**.
You cannot expect a good answer to your question because there are far more types which your number `1` belongs to than you really care about.
E.g.,

```
(typep 1 '(integer -6 42))
==> T
```

If you limit your attention to the [Standardized Atomic Type Specifiers](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_bc.htm), you can use something like

```
(defconstant *Standardized-Atomic-Type-Specifiers* ...) ; see Figure 4-2
(sort (remove-if-not (lambda (type) (typep 1 type)) 
                     *Standardized-Atomic-Type-Specifiers*)
      #'subtypep)
==> (BIT FIXNUM UNSIGNED-BYTE SIGNED-BYTE INTEGER RATIONAL REAL NUMBER ATOM T)
```

## Classes

Now, if you are willing to restrict your interest to **classes**, the situation becomes much more manageable.

First of all, [CLOS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_.htm) supports [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance), so "supertype path" is not uniquely defined a priori.

However, it *has* to be defined to determine the [method precedence order](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_ffab.htm), and this "path" is called [*class precedence list*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_ce.htm). It is computed by the standard [MOP](http://www.alu.org/mop/) function [`compute-class-precedence-list`](http://www.alu.org/mop/dictionary.html#compute-class-precedence-list):

```
(compute-class-precedence-list (class-of 1))
==> (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS INTEGER> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS RATIONAL> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS REAL>
     #<BUILT-IN-CLASS NUMBER> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>)
```

which is present in most Common Lisp implementations (use [`apropos`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apropo.htm) or [`find-all-symbols`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_a.htm) to find which package it is exported from).

You can use [`class-name`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_class_.htm) to get the names of the classes instead of their metaobjects:

```
(mapcar #'class-name (compute-class-precedence-list (class-of 1)))
==> (INTEGER RATIONAL REAL NUMBER T)
```

Note that [`bit`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_bit.htm), [`fixnum`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fixnum.htm), [`unsigned-byte`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_unsgn_.htm), [`signed-byte`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_sgn_by.htm), [`atom`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_atom.htm) are not in this list because they do not name standard [**classes**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_c.htm), just [**types**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_b.htm).

Answer (score 2):

That's not easy, IIRC.

I would use CLOS in some way:

```
CL-USER 34 > (loop for c = (class-of 1)
                   then (first (class-direct-superclasses c))
                   collect (class-name c)
                   until (eq c (find-class t)))
(FIXNUM INTEGER RATIONAL REAL NUMBER T)
```

Note that you need `CLASS-DIRECT-SUPERCLASSES` which is provided by CLOS implementations.